# its possible to create a low poly texture in substance designer?

Tags: graphics, textures, texture2d, substance, materials

i have a problem with creating a smooth low poly texture in substance designer.

plz see this below image :

[my target low-poly texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5IDj.png)

this is the texture i wanna create. but i cant do that.

this is my texture in substance designer :

[my low-poly texture in substance designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeA1K.png)

as you can see, my texture color is totally flat. but in the target texture, we see that this texture is not flat. we can create such a texture in substance designer?

my texture is flat and i wanna create a non flat low-poly texture